# Can't find node/web sub directories for Google Local Execution after build

Tags: actions-on-google, google-home

We're building the google home local execution support, based on the sample project (https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-local).

According to the [guide](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/local), when we run the `npm run build`, there should be two sub directories web and node generated in dist.
But after we did the build, there is only one bundle.js in the dist directory.
Any idea about it?

Answer (score 0):

When following the guide, you are recommended to use the [local-home-app](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/local#no-bundler) initiaizer:

```
npm init @google/local-home-app project-directory/ --bundler none # or other bundler options
```

This will setup your project using the correct configurations for various bundling tools so that it will generate two project types.

Additionally, the [local home sample](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-local) project [has been updated](https://github.com/actions-on-google/smart-home-local/commit/3ed6348816a15a4a3c334701f36728bd129882c9#diff-ac6ee8c82c5d20d9bb9c4d6ac70161d4) to show how to generate both types of artifacts:

```
"build": "npm run build-web && npm run build-node",
"build-web": "webpack --config webpack.config.web.js",
"build-node": "webpack --config webpack.config.node.js",
```